# D3 Line Chart JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I am trying to draw a line chart but am facing this error. I have already parsed my data but i dont know why am getting this error on 'var valueline':

please help

Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,679.1772151898734LNaN,693.132911392405LNaN,437.2784810126583LNaN,655.9177215189874LNaN,618.7025316455697LNaN,427.9746835443038LNaN,423.32278481012656LNaN,674.5253164556962LNaN,581.4873417721519LNaN,521.0126582278481LNaN,148.86075949367086LNaN,637.3101265822785LNaN

JSON data looks like this:

```
All=[{date: "01/09/2016", close: "12"}, {date: "01/11/2016", close: "9"},..]
```

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(5);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(5);



var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
 return d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
d3.json("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/trafficGraph.php", function(error, data) {
// var data= data.All;
console.log(data.All);
data.All.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data.All, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.All, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the filled area
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data.All)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

// Draw the x Grid lines
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )


    var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });


// Draw the y Grid lines
svg.append("g")            
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
    )

 var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });


// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", valueline(data.All));




// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

// Add the text label for the X axis
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                         (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date");

// Add the white background to the y axis label for legibility
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("class", "shadow")
    .text("Price ($)");

// Add the text label for the Y axis
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price ($)");

// Add the title
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))     
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")
    .text("Price vs Date Graph");

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parseDate is in the wrong format, meaning it goes null after parsing (and the line function returns NaNs).  Should be:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!  @Mark. Do you know how I can animate the graph while its initiating?

Comment: @ros, that's a rather broad question for a comment (and it's rather frowned upon here to "tack" on questions).  I suggest you close this question out and open a new one with the **specifics** of how you want to animate.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks @Mark!